# How to make a bot send DMs to a specific person?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a VA training section for my bot, it's supposed to send me the training type they've requested. But I've hit a wall and have no idea where to go from here.

I've looked online for a solution but haven't found any that work for me

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}request`) {
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);
  let sUser = user.get('My_ID_Goes_Here'); 
  message.sUser.send(args)
}
```

It is supposed to send the message argument to me, but it give me

> Reference Error: user is not defined

Comment: Assuming you have the guildMember: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=createDM then send to the returned DMChannel https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to send a DM to yourself using the bot. In this case, the [`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) can do exactly that.

The `Client` has a property named [`users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users). This property contains all the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) objects that your bot has cached (a.k.a., has interacted with.) The `users` property is a collection containing `User` objects, mapped by their IDs.

If you want to get your `User`, simply get the `User` from the collection that has your ID. Once you have your `User` object, you can send a DM to yourself using the [`send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send) method.

```js
// assuming "client" is your bot client
var me = client.users.get(MY_ID_HERE);
me.send("args");
```

Therefore, your code should be:

```js
    if(cmd === `${prefix}request`) {
        let args = messageArray.slice(1);
        let sUser = client.users.get('Your_ID_goes_here'); 

        sUser.send(args)
    }
```

You can also modify this to send direct messages to anyone, as long as you use their ID instead of yours.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I’ll add it to the bot as soon as I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "training-P1")) {
  let trainingstudent = message.mentions.users.first();
  let mentuor = message.mentions.users.second();
  mentour.send(trainingstudent "has requested P1 training");
}
```

That should work.